# get users nickname uploaded media

Tags: uploads, media, user-meta

I want to get the users nickname who uploaded a media file. I'm getting all media files with this code and want to link to the users nickname / profile

```
<?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => null, // any parent
                'numberposts' => -1,
                ); 
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $post) {

            ?>
            <?php $author = get_the_author($post->ID); ?> 

            <a href="myurl/<?php echo $author ?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" width="400" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>

            <?php 

                }
            }
            ?>
```

FIXED

```
<?php

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => null,
                'post_parent' => null, // any parent
                'numberposts' => -1,
                ); 
            $attachments = get_posts($args);
            if ($attachments) {
                foreach ($attachments as $post) {

            ?>
            $temp_post = get_post($post_id);
        $user_id = $temp_post->post_author;
        $user_login = get_the_author_meta('user_login',$user_id);

            <a href="myurl/<?php echo $user_login ?>"><img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>" width="400" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/></a>

            <?php 

                }
            }
            ?>
```

I'm not getting this to work. I have tried a lot of combinations, but the nickname is not getting rendered. Anyone can help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work

```
            $temp_post = get_post($post_id);
            $user_id = $temp_post->post_author;
            $user_login = get_the_author_meta('user_login',$user_id);
            echo $user_login;
```

Comment: Please explain _why_ this helps and _how_ it works.

Comment: Well the problem was I needed to make sure I got the uploaders ID first and in my first try I couldn't fetch it. So I found the second solution to see who is the author (uploader of the image) and using user_login displays the nickname/userlogin. Fixed it in the question